# Custom Header for listoflistings using Memoir and Listings Package

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, memoir, tocloft

Ok, I'm still working on a formatting various lists for my dissertation and have figured out how to get the format for the list of figures and tables right. I'm using custom page styles along the following lines:

```
% List of Figures

\copypagestyle{asu-lof}{asu}
    \makeevenhead{asu-lof}{Figure}{}{Page}
    \makeoddhead{asu-lof}{Figure}{}{Page}

\copypagestyle{asu-lof-init}{asu}
    \makeevenhead{asu-lof-init}{}{\printchaptertitle{\listfigurename}}{}
    \makeoddhead{asu-lof-init}{}{\printchaptertitle{\listfigurename}}{}

\renewcommand{\lofheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\printloftitle}[1]{}

\renewcommand{\afterloftitle}{
    \thispagestyle{asu-lof-init}
    Figure\hfill Page\par
}
```

In my main tex file, I'm declaring a new float environment for listings:

```
\newfloat[chapter]{listing}{lol}{Listing}
```

My overall template is based off of memoir. Here's my question: Are there analogues to the commands `\lofheadstart` and `\printloftitle` for the `\lstlistoflistings` command?

Comment: Without a compilable code example, this question is very unclear.

Comment: The `\lstlistoflistings` macro is not under the control of `memoir`'s mechanism